# Stop the mass retagging

Tags: discussion, tags

We have 1,540 questions and some users started to retag them in big numbers. Therefor fresh questions get hidden and disappear from the front site, where old, answered questions pop up, and also closed questions.

<strike>And those questions reappear in the RSS feed. Unfortunately "New Questions" doesn't have its own feed. (Hint from @MusiKk)</strike>

Retag questions while they're new. The current situation is disturbing, while well meant.

Comment: As you mentioned several days ago: best time to get "tumbleweed" badge :)

Comment: see http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/475/what-rss-feeds-other-than-recent-questions-are-available for feeds.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a problem here. First, it's just a temporary thing. Second, it's just one click to get to the [New Questions page](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions) which is ordered by creation date by default.

Also, IMHO it doesn't hurt reading and reviewing some old questions. Actually, it's quite interesting.

Comment: I must admit that I don't like it as well but my reason is that those questions reappear in the RSS feed. Unfortunately "New Questions" doesn't have its own feed.

Comment: @musiKk: "newest" is there: http://german.stackexchange.com/feeds/newest

Comment: @Takkat: Oh, thanks. I didn't find it because my RSS icon only shows for the main page, not the "New Questions" page. Weird...

Comment: @musiKk: I believe that is by design (it seems same on all SE sites I checked).